# Pytest, selenium, fixture throws an error after the first test InvalidSessionIdException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, singleton, fixtures

**I have a fixture file.**

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as chrome_options
from driver.singleton_driver import WebDriver


@pytest.fixture
def get_chrome_options():
    options = chrome_options()
    options.add_argument('chrome')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    return options


@pytest.fixture
def get_webdriver(get_chrome_options):
    options = get_chrome_options
    driver = WebDriver(options).driver
    return driver


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def setup(request, get_webdriver):
    driver = get_webdriver
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.close()
```

**File with my tests**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('setup')
class TestSteamPages:

    def test_first(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
        

    def test_second(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

As I understand it, after the first test, the function in the driver.close() fixture is triggered. But when the second test is run, the fixture does not restart the webdriver. An error

```
    venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:243: InvalidSessionIdException
============================================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================================
FAILED tests/test_first.py::TestSteamPages::test_second - 

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
ERROR tests/test_first.py::TestSteamPages::test_second - selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

For the driver, I use the Singleton pattern

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class WebDriver:
    class __WebDriver:
        def __init__(self, options):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

    driver = None

    def __init__(self, options):
        if not self.driver:
            WebDriver.driver = WebDriver.__WebDriver(options=options).driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `driver` is not reinitialized because of the singleton. `WebDriver.driver` is initialized before first test, so in the next time `setup` is running `if not self.driver` is `False`, because `self.driver` is not `None` anymore.

If you want to initialize the `WebDriver` every test don't use singleton

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_webdriver(get_chrome_options):
    options = get_chrome_options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    return driver
```

If you do want to initialize the `WebDriver` only once you can change fixtures scope to `'class'` (for all tests in `TestSteamPages`) or even move it to `conftest.py` with scope `'session'` for one driver instance for all the test. Note that in this case all the fixtures need to have `scope='class'`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request, get_webdriver):
    driver = get_webdriver
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.close()
```

Comment: If I set scope `'class'`, I get this error `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture get_webdriver with a class scoped request object, involved factories:
conftest.py:23:  def setup(request, get_webdriver)
conftest.py:16:  def get_webdriver(get_chrome_options)
============================================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================================
ERROR tests/test_first.py::TestSteamPages::test_first
ERROR tests/test_first.py::TestSteamPages::test_second
`

Comment: @JoLee I wrote about this in my answer *Note that in this case all the fixtures need to have `scope='class'`*